# When did mathematical logic start being applied in/ with computer science?

Tags: computer-science

I am going through articles about Turing machines which were introduced to solve the entscheidung problem by Alan Turing in 1936. To what I understand, all modern computers are essentially Turing machines, and mathematical logic is a critical concept in computing.

So, I want to ask when did it start being used with reference to Turing machines?

I see no mention of it when I go through these articles

Comment: I'm not sure it's propositional logic you want as much as mathematical logic, and even in there, a subset around computability (computable function, lambda calculus, etc etc).

Comment: The historical process is: [von Neumann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture#History) developed the modern architecture of "stored program computation" starting from Turing's abstract model of "human computation" and Universal Computing Machine.